# Is it possible to host a dot net web service on iMac?

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, apache, webserver

Usually dot net web services are hosted in IIS(Internet Information Server).

Since IIS is not compatible with iMac.

How to host it in iMac?

is there any plugin to apache that lets apache run it? like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX)

It's asp.net framework for unix based os. [it uses apache](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono)

Comment: it gives two version to download one is 86(32 bit) and 64 bit version but moutain lion seems to be x64_86 versions .I think it takes the best of both the worlds.Plz suggest me what to do

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mono, I simply know of it's existence. Therefore, I can't give further advice. Sorry

Comment: while searching for it i came accross the idea of creating a php web service and hosting it locally theni found out mac moutainlion comes with php 2.3 and apache 2.2 so i jus enabled the php parsing on apcache by uncommenting a php parsign line then i started the apache server usign terminal then i found the common virtual host it came under library/documents/ and then i put a sample php service there.any how my problem solved...as far as using a web service is concerned.If any one can guide me for hosting dot net web service that 'd be great...